# Flutter with direct dart firebase initialization still gets error on real device: Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

Flutter 2.8.1 using flutterfire - according to docs, should not need use the GoogleService-Info.plist file. This version states that it support direct dart initialization. Works fine on simulator, but when running on real iOS device - from Android Studio or XCode, I get the error about the plist file. flutterfire configure creates a valid firebase_options.dart file and main looks like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Output of flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

Comment: Have you found any workaround for this issue?  so Dart only initialisation doesn't work for iOS?  I just did this - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation#ios  My firebase initialization fails because it can't find GoogleServices-info.plist file. Any hints to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known issue:
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/7983

Need to keep an eye out for a solution....

Answer (score 0):

Do you have add the GoogleServices-info.plist file in XCode?

I mean do you have drag and drop it from Finder to Android Studio or XCode.

You need to drag and drop it to XCode.

Comment: I have *NOT* done this. I know that in the past this was a required step, but according to the flutterfire docs here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initializing-flutterfire
this step is no longer needed as the framework now supports direct dart initialization. As I mention above, the direct dart initialization does work in the simulator. I am able to connect to the firebase database, perform authentication activities, etc. All this without the plist file. But it does not work on a real device

Comment: Then i don't know

Comment: No problem -- appreciate that you tried!

Comment: I have also run into this same issue. Running it on a real device fails, but running it in the simulator works just fine. If you do happen to figure this out, let me know.

Comment: i will help you but i need more information, i know it has something to do with flutterfire but thats all i know. So please can you post more information like the whole error that comes when you run it on a real phone.

Comment: @sstakoff I am also facing the same issue on real device, did you fixed it

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue on the simulator.